# Is there any asp.net control has `Command` functionality without shape

Tags: asp.net, controls, command

Is there any asp.net control has [Command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.command.aspx) functionality without shape, I mean transparent box

I found`ImageButton` but it needs an image.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you thinking like an empty div?

You could try a linkbutton then just not put any text into it

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple ASP.NET button and make it invisible with CSS:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnTst" runat="server"
    style="visibility:hidden" Width="100" Height="100" CommandName="Test"/>
```

Comment: That won't create a transparent box, the display: none will remove it from the page entirely. Possibily visibility: none (if I remember correctly) will allow it to remain on screen but invisible, thus giving the desired transparent box effect.

Comment: Agreed, in this case the button must be properly sized.